# Get window size with python

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the window size with python?

I found things like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142342/get-window-position-size-with-python

But those are either Windows (as in the OS) specific, or require installs.
I'm guessing blender has this information somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

```
import bpy

wm = bpy.context.window_manager
for w in wm.windows:
    print(w.width)
    print(w.height)
```

Comment: I it also possible to get the display size?

Comment: What does display size mean? make a screenshot and let me know.

Comment: The size of the display in pixels. E.g. monitor resolution.

Comment: I didn't find monitor resolution in blender api.